# How to get Filtered from json per Item in Cart Razor MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to get filtered items size related to the product

this is Method json that returns by Id

```
  public ActionResult getProductSize(int prodID)
    {
        YAT.CMS.Shared.DAL.JAGUAREntities dbContext = new YAT.CMS.Shared.DAL.JAGUAREntities();
        var getsize = (from a in dbContext.ProductSizes
                       where a.ProductID == prodID
                       select a.Description).ToList();

        //var json_string = "{ Size: \"\" }";
        return Json(getsize, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and this is my View the section that hold category cart Description

```
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {

        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="imageCnt">
                <a href="@Url.Action("ProductDetails", "Product", new { ID = @Model[i].Id })">
                    <img class="bp-image" alt="@Model[i].EN_Name" src="@Url.Content("~/Admin/Admin_Cataloge/Product/" + @Model[i].Photo)" />
                </a>
                <input type="hidden" name="[@i].ProductID" value="@Model[i].Id"  />
            </td>
            <td class="titleCnt">
                <a href="@Url.Action("ProductDetails", "Product", new { ID = @Model[i].Id })">@Model[i].EN_Name</a>
            </td>
            <td class="priceCnt">@Model[i].Price<span class="currency">&nbsp;</span>
                <input id="@("Price" + i.ToString())" value="@Model[i].Price" type="hidden" />
            </td>
            <td class="quantityCnt">
                <span class="basketQuantityCnt">
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Quantity must be a number." data-val-required="The Quantity field is required." id="@("Quantity" + i)" name="[@i].Quantity" onkeypress="return restrictCharacters(this, event);" type="text" value="1"/>
                    <a class="deleteBtn" href="#" onclick="deleteBasketString(this,@Model[i].Id);"></a>
                    <a class="updateBtn" href="#" onclick="Calculate()"></a>
                    <a class="bq-plus" onclick="IncreaseQuantity(this);Calculate();"></a>
                    <a class="bq-minus" onclick="DecreaseQuantity(this);Calculate();"></a>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class="prodsize">
                <select id="selectNumber">
                    <option>Choose a number</option>
                   //Here where i want to add Filtered Size for item
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="subTotalCnt" id="@("total" + i)">@Model[i].Price<span class="currency">&nbsp;</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        total += Model[i].Price;
    }
```

how to do this in the Commented in view where I want to do this?

Comment: so what is the problem??

Comment: I've tagged the place where i want to add the filtered sizes per item